# Why is SSHFS so much less stable than SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, io, sshfs

If I'm on a very slow and/or slightly hiccupy internet connection, and I `ssh foo@bar.baz`, the connection will mostly stay up. If there's particularly bad lag, output (and echoed input) will take forever to appear on the screen, and my terminal may *appear* to be hung . . . but then, unless the connection has dropped entirely, the output will show up and life will go on. If the connection *has* dropped entirely, I will usually get a "broken pipe" error message, after which, my original shell (on my own machine) continues working. Occasionally, it may hang instead, but this is not typical.

If, on the other hand, I `sshfs foo@bar.baz:. ./qux`, even the slightest internet hiccup will leave the remote directory unreachable, and this, in turn, will hang almost any command or program that tries to read from or write to it. Not only that, but the programs in question will usually be impossible to get rid of with `kill -9`. I've even had the following happen, more than once:

- In a shell on one (virtual) terminal: `ssh foo@bar.baz` -- prompts for password, drops me into a shell in `foo`'s home directory
- In a shell on a second (virtual) terminal: `sshfs foo@bar.baz:. ./qux` -- prompts me for password, appears to work
- On that same terminal, less than a minute later: `ls qux` -- hangs
- Back to the first shell: No error message, `ls` displays promptly the contents of `foo`'s home directory, as expected
- Checking back to the second terminal -- ls is still hung, and proves to be unkillable, except by kill the shell I ran it in (and therefore any other long-running commands that I may foolishly have failed to nohup

Why is this? Why is mounting done with `sshfs` disrupted by hiccups that don't disrupt a remote shell accessed with `ssh`? And why do commands that are trying to read from a remote directory mounted with `sshfs` -- not even to write to it, which if interrupted, could leave a file in an incoherent state, but merely to *read* from it -- hang un`kill`ably?

Comment: You are comparing a network file system client and a remote login client. They really have not much to do with each other. Yes, they both use IP, TCP, and SSH (or an SSH extension). But that's about it. Check the manpage for `sshfs` to find ways to better deal with timeouts and reconnections. If you can define what your internet *hiccups* are and you ask here about ways to mitigate them, you might receive some advice. But that would be another question.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I get that they're not *comparable*, but . . .

Perhaps I'm confused, but my understanding is that `sshfs` works very roughly like this:
* An SSH connection is established and maintained,
* An SFTP session is used to interact with remote files over that SSH connection, and
* FUSE is used to mount a "filesystem" that is (effectively) an interface to that SFTP session.

(cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If this is at least approximately right, then it seems like `ls ./qux` is permanently hung as a result of some network condition, then one of the following must be true:

1. The SSH connection is permanently hung or has crashed,

2. The SSH connection is still functional, but the SFTP session is nevertheless permanently hung or has crashed,

3. The SFTP session is functional, but either the interface between it and the FUSE process or the FUSE process itself is hung, crashed, or somehow giving `ls` permahang-inducing output.

Comment: (cont. (again)) If it is common for a remote login `ssh` session to still be working fine (albeit probably lagging) when this is happening, but not vice versa, that seems to imply that (1) is not the explanation. And (2) and (3) both seem "unreasonable," in a way that (1) (or, at least, its "crashed" version) does not -- if the internet connection is just plain not reliable enough to sustain the use of a certain protocol, that's one thing. But whether the data I send and receive over a given protocol (`ssh) can reliably reach its destination shouldn't depend on what that data is.